# Entity Framework 7 Create in-memory implementation of DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Sorry I am new to Entity Framework..

I want to  created a TestDbSet that provides an in-memory implementation of DbSet in EF 7.

```
public class TestDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity> 
        where TEntity : class 
    { 
        ObservableCollection<TEntity> _data; 
        IQueryable _query; 


    public TestDbSet() 
    { 
        _data = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>(); 
        _query = _data.AsQueryable(); 
    } 

    public override TEntity Add(TEntity item) 
    { 
        _data.Add(item); 
        return item; 
    } 

    public override TEntity Remove(TEntity item) 
    { 
        _data.Remove(item); 
        return item; 
        } 
 }
```

I am getting error in Add method that return type must be `EntityEntry<T>` to match Overriden Dbset member.

I tried to change method signature but I am not sure how to return item as EntityEntry

```
 public override EntityEntry<T> Add(T item) 
        {
           _data.Add(item);
            return  item;
        }
```

I could not find similar issue. Can you guide me how we implement in EF 7.. I know it will work in EF 6..

Comment: What do you want to do with this implementation ?

Comment: For unit testing..

Comment: I think it's better to ceate a DbSet that inherits from List<T> or Collection<T>, also you will handle the behavior for generated values suc as Identity in SqlSever

Comment: I could not get you clearly. If I just inherit List<T> how can I override Save , Add etc.. Can you explain with sample..

Answer (score 3):

For testing without real DB you may [use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) package

Comment: Yes in memory is working. But I want to Mock my DBSets and also I have Bulk updates for which I am using Stored Procedure.

Comment: You would get `EntityEntry` from DbContext. You cannot use `DbSet` without involving DbContext since DbSets are part of the context. In your code snippet, you are not involving the context anywhere. So if you don't want to use the context as suggest in comments of question, you are better by inheriting from List or collection.

Comment: @Smit : I was try to replicate this [Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314431(v=vs.113).aspx ) in EF 7 and I could not override the dbset methods in TestDbset class..Let me know I how can achieve returning EntityEntry..

Comment: EF6 & EF core are pretty different. Given the changes in the return type of functions on `DbSet<T>`, the article which applied to EF6 cannot be ported. Given the usages of internal type and close coupling with context for DbSet, at this point of time best bet is to use EF.InMemory package. You can extend from that package if you want to add more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I know this is very old thread. But thought if this helps. I managed to override the Add method for EF Core by returning null. As we are just the data item into list so it doesn't matter if we return null unless you need ChangeTracking Object.

```
    public override EntityEntry<T> Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by the following code

```
 public override EntityEntry<T> Add(T item) 
 {
           _data.Add(item);
            return item as EntityEntry<T>;
 }
```